# How get a specific value from a query in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am just starting learning about Linq. I wrote some examples but there is a doubt that I haven't been able to solve.

I am working with the `Northwind` database, I just used the tool called `SqlMetal` in order to make all the modeling.

Right now I just wrote the following query:

```
var q = from c in db.Customers
        from o in c.Orders
        where c.City == "London"
        select new { c, o };
```

I know that this query brings to me a resulting set of data that contains all the columns of the `Customers` and `Orders` tables for the given condition (`c.City == "London"`). But my question is:

After executing that query, **How can I get the value of the column `Customers.CustomerID` and `Orders.OrderID` FROM THE VARIABLE `q`?**

Maybe this is a silly question but I have been struggling with this for a couple hours, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var theSoleItem = q.First();
theSoleItem.CustomerID
theSoleItem.OrderID
```

Also, if that was the only columns you cared about, your initial query would be faster with:

```
select new {c.CustomerID, o.OrderID}
```

You could also change the names as you go:

```
select new {CustID = c.CustomerID, OrdID = o.OrderID}
```

The latter being the only option if rather than directly referencing a property, you reference a method call.

Comment: Not exactly perfectly if there's more than one matching record. Note that rather than `First()` you can also do `foreach(var item in q)`. Since you're experimenting now, you should do so with both, as both will come up a lot in real code.

Answer (score 1):

The variable q is now a sequence of anonymous objects that have two objects in it: Customer and Order. You can easy iterate over it:

```
foreach(var item in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CustomerID = " + item.CustomerID + " order ID = " + item.OrderID);
}
```

Comment: Hi, that was my first approach, but, when I iterated over it, the variable `item` did not contain a definition for `CustomerID`, `OrderID` or any column.

Comment: Yeah, if my answer worked, this should too. Must have had some other error.

Comment: I realized what's the problem here, we just need to write `item.c.CustomerId` instead of `item.CustomerId`

Comment: Ah yes. But if you do the sort of `select` where you create an anonymous object with just the fields you want, then you do `item.CustomerId`. Those sort of selects are lighter on the database, so a good idea most of the time.